# OpenGL ES 2.0 Derivative Texture

Tags: iphone, objective-c, opengl-es, glsl

I have an OpenGL ES 2.0 based iPhone app which I am running to a bit of OpenGL ES trouble.

I am trying to complile a fragment shader which computes/displays the derivative of an input texture. My fragment shader code is:

```
 varying highp vec2 textureCoordinate;

 uniform sampler2D inputImageTexture;
 uniform sampler2D inputImageTexture2;

 void main(void)
 {
   mediump vec4 derivData = vec4(dFdx(texture2D(inputImageTexture, textureCoordinate).xyz, 0.0);

   gl_FragColor = derivData;
 }
```

However, this fails the compile. If I take out the dFdX, it compiles just fine.

Does anyone have any experience with this? I'd eventually like to calculate the derivative with respect to Y as well, then merge them seeing how the input texture is an image.

I've been struggling on this for a few days now so any advice you have would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Unfortunately, `dFdx()` isn't a built-in function in OpenGL ES 2.0. The full list of these functions can be found in this handy reference card: http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/reference_cards/OpenGL-ES-2_0-Reference-card.pdf

Comment: Actually, I may be slightly wrong on that. It looks like the `GL_OES_standard_derivatives` extension might be present on iOS devices, giving support for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5959542/ios-simulator-gl-oes-standard-derivatives . However, the Simulator appears to lack this support.

Comment: "However, this fails the compile." When it failed to compile, did it give you some kind of error message? Could you post that error message?

Comment: I can confirm that `GL_OES_standard_derivatives` was present on my iPhone 4, when last I took a list of supported extensions. So I'd consider Brad's second comment to be an answer.

Comment: One of the closing parenthesis is lost

Answer (score 18):

All iOS hardware that supports ES 2.0 will support the GL_OES_standard_derivatives extension: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/OpenGLESPlatforms/OpenGLESPlatforms.html

However, you don't get it "for free". In your fragment shader, you must add the following at the top (from http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/OES/OES_standard_derivatives.txt):

```
#extension GL_OES_standard_derivatives : enable
```

All the info in the comments to the first answer is mostly accurate, but without this piece you'll continue to get the following error:

```
ERROR: 0:15: Call to undeclared function 'dFdx'
ERROR: 0:16: Call to undeclared function 'dFdy'
```

This threw me for a loop, but once I added the enable line, it seems to work on both the device and the simulator (haven't actually evaulate that it works on both, but it does compile).

Comment: Thank you! This will also permit use of the fwidth function.

Comment: Just what I needed to know. Thanks!